# Comparing two face opencv

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv, window

I am new in opencv. I am trying to make a program which capture video from webcam and show the face on the video is exist in the directory or not. I already complete face detect from webcam. Now i jast need  to compare the similarity of detected face with the directory image face. Please help me some one...
I am using
C++
MSVC 2010
OpenCV 2.1

Comment: Check this article http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/faceRecognition.html

Comment: What have *you* tried? What worked? What didn't? What *specific* problems are you facing? ("this is my assignment, anyone willing to code it for me?" is the exact opposite of "specific"; also, C++ or C? They're not exactly interchangeable...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenCV's face detection methods. They have a very good tutorial in their website.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection/

Comment: I already did face detection. I jast need to compare the detected face to the directory image face.

Answer (score 0):

You can see to [libface](http://libface.sourceforge.net/file/Home.html). It can detect and recognise faces.